# Can't compile old project after upgrade to Xcode 9/10 : "Expected unqualified-id" Error in GLKit / common.h

Tags: ios, xcode, glkit

I have a IOS project I need to update.
It works fine in Xcode 8, but after upgrading to Xcode 9 or 10 (tried both) it won't compile anymore.

I get "Expected unqualified-id" parse error in the file "`common.h`" which is included from `GLKit.h`.

The line with the error is the following:

```
} /* extern "C" */
```

I think perhaps a } to much, however I can't even edit this file as it belongs to apples libraries and is read only.

If I go back to Xcode 8 it immediately works again.

Comment: Your target is probably configured to use the `Compiler default` dialect for C and/or C++, which potentially is different for each Xcode major release. You need to set a specific (and correct) language dialect in your build options. I don't know which dialect will work, so you may have to experiment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8RVa.png

Comment: Or you may have a `common.h` in your project which is interfering with the one from the framework: in that case, you may want to rename your file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what happened. I had the following somewhere:

```
#define MIN(X, Y) (((X) < (Y)) ? (X) : (Y))
```

This messed up with something in the common.h.

Defining this after the include of the common.h solved the problem. I dont know why this only happens on XCode 9+